# how do i fix my problem with my tuple in python

Tags: python, tuples

i have a problem in python i have been told that is is to do with the tuple in the code the idle gives me this error after login

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
artist, song = choice.split()
```

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

this is my full code

```
import random
import time

x = 0
print("welcome to music game please login below")

AuthUsers = {"drew":"pw","masif":"pw","ishy":"pw"}
#authentication
PWLoop = True

while PWLoop:
    userName = input("what is your username?")
#asking for password
    password = (input("what is the password?"))

    if userName in AuthUsers:
        if AuthUsers.get(userName) == password:
            print("you are allowed to play")
            PWLoop = False
        else:
            print("invalid password")
    else:
        print("invalid username")


#GAME

#SETTING SCORE VARIBLE
score = 0

#READING SONGS

read = open("SONGS.txt", "r")
songs = read.readline()
songlist = []

for i in range(len(songs)):
    songlist.append(songs[i].strip())



while x == 0:
    #RANDOMLY CHOSING A SONG

    choice = random.choice(songlist)
    artist, song = choice.split()


#SPLITTING INTO FIRST WORDS

songs = song.split()
letters = [word[0] for word in songs]


#LOOp

for x in range(0,2):
    print(artist, "".join(letters))
    guess= str(input(Fore.RED + "guess the song"))
    if guess == song:
        if x == 0:
            score = score + 2
            break
        if x == 1:
            score = score + 1
            break


#printing score
```

Comment: can  you paste sample of `"SONGS.txt"`?

Comment: `choice.split()` only has one element, and thus can't be assigned to two variables.

Comment: this is the sample of SONGS.txt

Comment: Thiago Silva,Dave ft AJ Tracey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `artist, song = choice.split()` to:

```
song, artist = choice.split(',')
```

this will fix your problem.
according to the data that you given, you should split with `,`.\

Comment: File "\\computing.py", line 46, in <module>
    song, artist = choice.split(',')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Answer (score 1):

Issue is due to these two lines:

```
choice = random.choice(songlist)
# choice will be single item from songlist chosen randomly.
artist, song = choice.split() # trying to unpack list of 2 item
# choice.split() -> it will split that item by space
# So choice must be a string with exact one `space`
# i.e every entry in songlist must be string with exact one `space`
```

As the format of your file https://pastebin.com/DNLSGPzd

And To fix the issue just split by `,`

Updated code:

```
artist, song = choice.split(',')
```

Comment: # trying to unpack list of 2 item
# choice.split() -> it will split that item by space
# So choice must be a string with exact one `space`
# i.e every entry in songlist must be string with exact

Comment: how do i fix it then can you please edit the code so the problem is repaired

Comment: @ZafirAhmedPatel paste the content of file in exact format (line by line) by editing you question

Comment: i have above as another coment

Comment: @ZafirAhmedPatel format is most important part of file. You just can't paste the sample in comment section correctly. Update you question there you can paste that sample in correct format(line by line) or paste here -> https://pastebin.com/  and share the link